# Examples of $\omega_{1}<\alpha<\omega_{2}$ definable

Tags: model-theory, ordinals

Can you think of any examples of definable ordinals between $\omega_{1}<\alpha<\omega_{2}$?

I am trying to show that countable $M\prec (H(\aleph_{2},\in)$ contains ordinals $>\omega_{1}$.

Is $2^{\omega_{1}}$ one?
Thanks

Comment: $\omega_1+1$ would be one.

Comment: $\omega_1+42$ is an uncountable answer.

Comment: @ArthurFischer Is it the style now to call $2^\alpha$ an exponent? When I went to school in a bygone century, I would have called $\alpha$ the exponent, $2$ the base, and $2^\alpha$ a power. (But don't ask me about multiplier and multiplicand, I never could keep those straight.)

Answer (score 1):

Even if you don't show any direct example, it is easy to show that.

Note that your structure doesn't have a maximal ordinal. So if $\omega_1$ is in $M$ it cannot be the maximal one. Then to show it is definable is not hard either. For example $\omega_1+\omega$ is definable.

Finally, as Arthur points out, $2^\delta=\sup\{2^\beta\mid\beta<\delta\}$ for a limit ordinal $\delta$, therefore $2^{\omega_1}=\sup\{2^\alpha\mid\alpha<\omega_1\}$. It can be shown by induction that $\alpha^\beta$ is countable, if both ordinals are countable. Therefore $2^{\omega_1}$ is the supremum of countable ordinals, but it has to be uncountable and therefore it must be $\omega_1$ itself.